# Insert y Select en MySQL

Tags: mysql

tengo un pequeño problema con una base de datos... ya que lo que necesito es poder mezclar dichos datos. Actualmente así está mi BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo necesito que vaya quedando así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En teoria debo agregar la MATRIZ  con (intermareal) y (submareal)... el tema es que son mas de 1000 registros, por lo que hacerlo de manera manual me llevaria dias...

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar con un Script, sería ideal.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No tengo a la mano una base de datos MyQL para probar, pero a grandes rasgos una propuesta sería construir un cursor para recorrer la tabla y para cada uno de los registros, concatenarle al campo matriz las descripciones adicionales que necesitas y realizar los dos inserts:

```
DECLARE finaliza INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE nuevaMatriz varchar(128);
DECLARE idEnsayo int;
DECLARE analisis varchar(64);
DECLARE matriz varchar(128);
...
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finaliza = TRUE;
DECLARE micursor CURSOR FOR SELECT idEnsayo ,analisis, matriz, metodologias, laboratorio FROM mitabla;

  OPEN micursor;          
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH micursor INTO idEnsayo, analisis, matriz;

    IF finaliza THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    select nuevaMatriz = concat(matriz,' (Intermareal)')
    insert into mitabla values (idEnsayo, analisis, nuevaMatriz);

    select nuevaMatriz = concat(matriz,' (Submareal)')
    insert into mitabla values (idEnsayo, analisis, nuevaMatriz);

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE micursor;
```